# Unity 2D Circle Collider Shaky Movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collider

So, I'm having a problem with shaky movement in a very simple 2D platformer, with a square player, using a circle collider. The player's movement is shaky, not the ground. I think it's a problem with the colliders, because I've been on another post trying to fix the script, and I think I did it. I've been trying to fix this for quite a while.

```
public float moveSpeed;
public float jumpHeight;
Rigidbody2D rb;

void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpHeight);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(-moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you maybe make a small gif or video highlighting the issue? With this code and description it's a bit hard to know what you mean

Comment: I should be able to provide a video soon, but right now I'm a little too busy.